# Can Stringformatter reuse arguments?

Tags: java, string

I'm using `String.format` to create a formatted string with arguments. Is it somehow possible to tell the formatter to reuse an argument multiple times?

```
String.format(%s FOO %s %s, "test"); //desired output: "test FOO test test"
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `$` specifier for this. The number preceding the `$` indicates the argument number, starting from 1:

```
String.format("%1$s FOO %1$s %1$s", "test")
```

Comment: Funfact: I just googled this today and came back to my 4 yrs old question :)

Answer (score 9):

Just as a complement to Keppils answer:
When you've started numbering one of your arguments, you have to number them all, or else the result will not be as expected.

```
String.format("Hello %1$s! What a %2$s %1$s!", "world", "wonderful");
// "Hello world! What a wonderful world!"
```

would work. While

```
String.format("Hello %1$s! What a %s %1$s!", "world", "wonderful");
// "Hello world! What a world world!"
```

would not work. (But does not throw any errors, so this might go unnoticed.)

Answer (score 6):

```
String.format("%1$s FOO %1$s %1$s", "test");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.format("%s FOO %<s %<s", "test")
```

Relative indexing is used when the format specifier contains a '<' ('\u003c') flag which causes the argument for the previous format specifier to be re-used. If there is no previous argument, then a MissingFormatArgumentException is thrown.

```java
formatter.format("%s %s %<s %<s", "a", "b", "c", "d")
 // -> "a b b b"
 // "c" and "d" are ignored because they are not referenced
```

Source (search for 'Argument Index'): https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

Note, if using numbered variables, either number all variables or DON'T start using the numbered notation until after all variables are used.

e.g.
`String.format(%s and %s and %1$s is four, "one , "two");`

results in "one and two and one is four"

BUT
`String.format(%1$s and %s and %1$s is four, "one , "two");`

results in "one and one and one is four"

Numbering the variables seems to cut off further reading in of variables.